# Why @Column might not work for methods?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a Spring Boot application with JPA and Hibernate Maven dependencies. Database is PosgreSQL.

I would like to **create fields in a database based on methods**.

So I have an entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    protected String name;

    @Transient
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar myXMLDate;

    protected Calendar myDateProperty;

    @Column(name = "my_date")
    private Calendar isCalendar() {
        return new GregorianCalendar(myXMLDate.getYear(), myXMLDate.getMonth(), myXMLDate.getDay());
    }

    @Column(name = "my_str")
    public String myStr() {
        return "My string";
    }


    public MyEntity() {
    }
}
```

However I receive the following structure:

[image]

All annotations on methods **are ignored**.

Could anyone please give me some advice why it might happen and how to create needed fields properly?

Comment: Why do you have some annotations on FIELDS and some on METHODS ? Use one or the other!

Comment: @NeilStockton It is for getting the XMLGregorianCalendar value and convert it to Calendar or Date format that JPA understands. Second method with String is just for testing purpose.

Comment: And as I said ... USE annotations on EITHER FIELDS OR METHODS, but NOT BOTH. You persist EITHER the fields, or the properties (getters)

Comment: @NeilStockton OK. You could show your approach in your answer and show some code.

Comment: "My approach" is demonstrated in any basic JPA documentation, there is no need to duplicate it here. Why not look at the documentation for the JPA provider you have selected? It will tell you this important rule

Comment: @NeilStockton +1 this approach is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution. So that you can **receive values from methods** you should add *@Access* annotations and also make *@Transient* variables.

So Hibernate will create neccesary fields and during commit will **use values from methods to fulfill** them.

Also here is an example of how to **convert XMLGregorianCalendar to Calendar** -
 the format that Hibernate can use successfully.

Here is a working example:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name="test_my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    @Transient
    protected String name;

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    @Transient
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar myXMLDate;

    @Transient
    private Calendar calendarDate;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "calendar_date")
    private Calendar getCalendarDate() {
        return new GregorianCalendar(myXMLDate.getYear(), myXMLDate.getMonth(), myXMLDate.getDay());
    }

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "my_str_name")
    public String getName() {
        return "My string";
    }

    //...setters here

    public MyEntity() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods must follow, Java Bean convention; precisely, **public** `Getters` and `Setters`. Moveover, properties must exist. Try this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    private Long id;
    protected String name;
    private Calendar myDate;
    private String myStr;

    @Transient
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar myXMLDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "my_date")
    public Calendar getMyDate() {
      return myDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "my_str")
    public String getMyStr() {
      return myStr;
    }

    // I don't get its purpose; hence not touching it.
    private Calendar isCalendar() {
        return new GregorianCalendar(myXMLDate.getYear(), myXMLDate.getMonth(), myXMLDate.getDay());
    }
}
```

Refs:

- [List of types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) Hibernate understand by default.
- How to make Hibernate to [understand your type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type).

Comment: See my addendum.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. I have tested on String field. Also as I understand you should add @Transient  annotation on private fields - in other case Hibernate will create fields based on private variables.

Comment: It means that I receive the same structure as in the question without "my_date" or "my_str" fields in database. Of course I use @Transient at private variables.

Comment: If you define that as `@Transient`, why on earth it will create those as a field?

Comment: OK. You just use wrong types in your answer. Please use XMLGregorianCalendar type and Hibernate will give you an Exception of not defined type if you don't annotate this field as @Transient. Also you have value ONLY in myXMLDate variable after you will parse XML. Your added value of myDate will be NULL always. But I need to save myXMLDate in database.

Comment: Yes, thats different. There are certain types, what Hibernate understands, others it doesn't -- unless you force it to. It doesn't understand `XMLGregorianCalendar`, hence the exception.

Comment: +1 for efforts. However if I want to return some value in the getter in your example like "return new GregorianCalendar(2017, 11, 30);" - this value will not be saved in database after commit.

Comment: No, indeed. You need to have a respective `setter` to set the value of a property; once set it should persist.